# Jörn Zaefferer's jQuery Validate: How to configure a rule to accept a name[#]

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

The `form` is a view cart. The shopper can change the QTY for any item. Each `qty` input is `name="quantity[row_id]"` with `row_id` = `0`, `1`, `2`..., etc.

I want the value to be required and numeric (read: integer). I've tried this:

```
$("#my-view-cart").validate({
  rules: {
    quantity: {
      required: true,
      digits: true
    }
  }
});
```

I've tried rules with `quantity[*]` and `quantity*` but that was futile.

If there's an example in the plugin's doc I didn't see it.

Or perhaps there's another way to do this with this plugin? I'm using the above rule on the product add to cart page but that's just a single input. With multiple inputs I'm stuck.

Comment: You could just use classes to setup the validations rather than declaring them in code. `<input name="quantity[0]" class="required digits" />` and `$("#my-view-cart").validate()` let the plugin handle the names however it wants.

Comment: @KevinB Thx. I thought I tried digits and it didn't work in the class. I'll try again.

Comment: See my answer demonstrating how to use `class` along with a working demo.

Comment: Thx to both of you the class stuff worked. Not sure where I went wrong the first time. One more Q...how can I tell if the form currently has any errors. Long story, but the Checkout click is not a submit, it's a link. I don't want to allow a checkout click if an error is showing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like writing a whole new question might be warranted.  Basically, without seeing the code, you'd just use `$('#myform').valid()` to return a boolean value to test whether the form passes validation.  Something like, `if ($('#myform').valid()) { //form is valid };`

Comment: I also edited my answer to expand upon my comments about your follow-up question.  However, generally, if a follow-up question doesn't have much to do with the original question, a new one should be posted.  Since it seems like your original question was resolved, please select and "accept" an answer below.  Thanks.

Comment: If your question has been solved, please accept an answer below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `name` of the input in quotes:

```
$("#my-view-cart").validate({
  rules: {
    "quantity[1]": {
      required: true,
      digits: true
    }
  }
});
```

or do as Kevin B says in the comments and add `class="required digits"` to the input element.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I stumbled into putting it in quotes. But is there a way to wild card the index? In other words instead having to repeat [0], [1], etc. - an entry for each - I can just do something like [*] (which doesn't work)?

Answer (score 1):

> "Or perhaps there's another way to do this with this plugin?"

Use the built-in `rules()` method to add rules and assign them by `class`.  [See documentation.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules)

Note:  You **must** call this method *after* you call `.validate()`.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" class="myclass" name="whatever" />
    <input type="text" class="myclass" name="something" />
    <input type="text" class="myclass" name="another" />
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#form").validate({
    // my options
});

// the following method must come AFTER .validate()
$('#form').find('.myclass').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Required input",
            digits: "Please only enter digits"
        }
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kSFKE/)

---

**EDIT:**

OP's comment:

> "I don't want to allow a checkout click if an error is showing. Any
>   thoughts?"

You'd just use [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to return a boolean value to test whether the form passes validation. Something like...

```
if ($('#form').valid()) {
    // form passes validation, allow your click
} else {
    // form fails validation, do something else
}
```

If this is not what you needed, posting a new question about this unrelated issue would be warranted.

Comment: Oh. Nice. I didn't know the rules can be customized for my own classes. Wow. I thought they were just for fields.

Comment: @ChiefAlchemist, oh yeah, powerful stuff.  This can be used to handle form fields that are added dynamically too... as long as they have the proper `class`.

Comment: @politus, yes, that's anther possibility [although it's a little bit different](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules).  My answer using `rules(add)` simply **assigns** some rules on chosen elements, whereas `addClassRules` simply **creates** new compound rules, without assigning them (that's still up to you).  The latter would not be used for validating _dynamically_ created fields.

Comment: @Sparky I agree it is basically the same thing, but just out of interest I tried it with a dynamically created field and it does work with them also http://jsfiddle.net/SaLNp/5/

Comment: @politus, interesting... indeed it does, [but not always](http://jsfiddle.net/SaLNp/6/).  Like I said, the difference is one is _creating_ new rules and the other is _assigning_ existing rules.  It all depends on each unique situation, which would be less verbose.

Comment: If you were going to dynamically add a field, you would add the new input field and then use `.rules(add)` to add your rule to it.  It would not make sense to _create_ new rules each time you simply add an `input`.  Anyway, it's a moot point for this particular OP.